# NullPointerException on this line if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete"))

Tags: java

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String forward="";
    String action = request.getParameter("action");

    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")){
        int userId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userId"));
        dao.deleteUser(userId);
        forward = LIST_USER;
        request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers());    
    } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")){
        forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
        int userId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userId"));
        User user = dao.getUserById(userId);
        request.setAttribute("user", user);
    } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("listUser")){
        forward = LIST_USER;
        request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers());
    } else {
        forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
    }

    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
    view.forward(request, response);
}}
```

Comment: `if (action!=null && action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")){` (Check if `action` is not `null` before you use it).

Comment: Maybe you should also see if there is an <input> with the parameter name="action"... 

I said this because it seems that you are creating some website and this variable is null because you don't have any inputs with the name "action"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.getParameter("action");` is null here

so use

```
 if (action!=null && action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")){
       int userId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userId"));
    dao.deleteUser(userId);
    forward = LIST_USER;
    request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers());    
} else if (action!=null && action.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")){
    forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
    int userId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userId"));
    User user = dao.getUserById(userId);
    request.setAttribute("user", user);
} else if (action!=null && action.equalsIgnoreCase("listUser")){
    forward = LIST_USER;
    request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers());
} else {
    forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
}
```

Comment: it will not goto top second check if first fails

Comment: Please explain how it will do the second condition

Comment: @hsz It's AND operator  and not OR. So, it will not reach second condition

Comment: Answer posted before contained only one `action != null` test, so it was the reason to downvote. For now it's ok but SO doesn't allow me to remove dovnwote.

Answer (score 24):

Change it to, you can make the constant part as the main object and then check the variable part whether it is equal

```
"delete".equalsIgnoreCase(action)
```

Comment: This for me seemed a little "wrong way around" the first time I saw it, but the null-safety it gives you is really nice!

Answer (score 1):

though i'd prefer Arun P Johny's solution maybe this helper method is useful too:

```
public String getParameter(HttpServletRequest request, String parameterName, String defaultvalue) {
    String result = request.getParameter(parameterName);

    return (result != null) ? result : defaultValue;
}
```

and then call

```
String action = getParameter(request, "action", "");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use

```
 String action = request.getParameter("action")+"";
```

So all the other checks wont give a NPE.

Comment: doesn't that throw a NPE if the method returns `null`?